# How can I keep Netty NIODatagram channels open throughout a "session"

Tags: netty, nio, channel, datagram

I am trying to convert a Mina project to use Netty, and have been stumped trying to come up with appropriate code to model.

My NioDatagram client has to exchange a number of authentication packets with a server during a virtual "session".  I am trying to reuse the channel and avoid the overhead of channel creation and teardown.

Most of the few NioDatagram examples I have run into quailfy as toys.  They send a single packet doing lots of things like:

```
try {
    handleRxDatagram(ctx, packet);
} finally {
    **ctx.close();**
} 

ch.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(bbuf, toAddress)).sync();
boolean succ = ch.closeFuture().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (!succ) {
    System.err.println("query timeout!");
    **ch.close().sync();**
}
```

No matter what I try I either wind up packets not being sent, or not being received.

No doubt a lot of my problems are caused by my ignorance and unfamiliarity with Netty, but NIO UDP seems to be the poor poster child of the Netty project.  It should not be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking for.... its not different then `SocketChannel` beside that you write and receive `DatagramPacket`. If you dont want to close the `DatagramChannel` just don't close it.

Comment: I appreciate the rapid response from the acknowledged expert.  Would you be able to point me to some non-trivial example?